# Using grep to match variables in one column to a string of text in another column

Tags: r

I need to match a string in the first variable with a string in the second variable and then return true or false in the third column.

Here is my data

````
regex <- c("cat", "dog", "mouse") 
text<- c("asdf.cat/asdf", "asdf=asdf", "asdf=mouse asdf")
df <- data.frame(regex, text)```
````

And I need an output like this

| regex | text | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat | asdf.cat/asdf | 1 |
| dog | asdf=asdf | 0 |
| mouse | asdf=mouse asdf | 1 |

I have tried using grepl but I cant figure out how to use it in a dataframe.

```
df$result <- as.integer(grepl("cat", df$text))
```

This will work for the first row only

I have also tried the following code which works to filter out the matches but I want to keep them all in and just return true or false.

```
df %>%
  filter(unlist(Map(function(x, y) grepl(x, y), regex, text)))
```

As you can see it is complicated by the text string containing various characters

I feel like this should be easy but I cant wrap my head round it!!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `grepl`, use `str_detect` which is vectorised for the `pattern` and `string`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(result= +(str_detect(text, regex)))
```

-output

```
   regex            text result
1   cat   asdf.cat/asdf      1
2   dog       asdf=asdf      0
3 mouse asdf=mouse asdf      1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(regex = c("cat", "dog", "mouse"), text = c("asdf.cat/asdf", 
"asdf=asdf", "asdf=mouse asdf")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```